# How can I add a caption to a restructuredText table?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a grid table in restructuredText. Is there a way to add a caption to it?

```
+----------+---------+
|Name      |Age      |
+==========+=========+
|Bill      |39       |
+----------+---------+
|Jane      |38       |
+----------+---------+
```

There's no directive, so it's not like the figures:

```
.. figure:: strawberryicecream.png

   Strawberry Ice Cream
```

Comment: What about the `table` directive? It takes one optional argument, the table title. http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table

Comment: I tried it earlier but it didn't work... but figured out that I forgot to indent the table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh, never mind, the [`table` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table) works. I tried it earlier but didn't indent the table definition properly.

```
.. table:: Personnel

   +----------+---------+
   |Name      |Age      |
   +==========+=========+
   |Bill      |39       |
   +----------+---------+
   |Jane      |38       |
   +----------+---------+
```